# Deduce timestamp of block for chains without timestamp pallet

Tags: data-analytics

Usually when looking for when the block was created I refer the timestamp.set extrinsic.
But some chains in the past were not using the timestamp pallet as part of their runtime, for reference statemine and statemint when they were using shell-runtime initially.

So in these cases how does one go about estimating the timestamp of the block.

Answer (score 2):

You can see when that block was included in the relay chain as ParachainInclusion CandidateBacked. It must have been created before that and after the prior block from that parachain.

Comment: Is there more documentation for the ParachainInclusion CandidateBacked event about when its triggered?